# Cordova Ionic framework internet allow-intent not working

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using condova 6.0 and Ionic ver 1.7.14, designing an Android mobile app, that works with internet connection. On the Ionic Lab it works fine, but when I generate the Android App and Installed on my Galaxy S4, does not connect to internet. I already review some forums, I'm using cordova whitelist, and add some extra properties to my config.xml file and still does not work.

Here in my config.xml file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <widget id="com.ionicframework.viclab151106" version="0.0.1"   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
   <name>VicLab</name>
     <description>
        An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.
     </description>
     <author email="caribesoft@gmail.com" href="http://caribesoft.net/">
       Victor Rodriguez
     </author>
      <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
      <allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
      <allow-navigation href="data:*" />    
      <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
      <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
      <access origin="*" />
      <content src="index.html"/>
      <access origin="*"/>
      <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
      <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
      <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
      <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
      <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
      <feature name="StatusBar">
         <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true"/>
      </feature>
      </widget>`enter code here`
```

Also, here is my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">

<title>VicLab</title>

<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
<link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
-->

<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<!-- your app's js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>`enter code here`
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/whitelist.js"></script>
 </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
  </html>
```

In advance thank you for any help !

Answer (score 0):

I am using this meta and it works well. Maybe this is your problem

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src 'self' data:; default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Also, this is the config.xml part

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<access origin="*" />
```

I am not using Ionic, but I think it would be the same

---

**NOTE TO ALL:** This answer uses an unrestricted whitelist filter - intended for development only.
**THIS EXAMPLE IS INSECURE. IT IS UP TO YOU TO SECURE YOUR APP.**
 In addition, your app maybe reject by Google and Apple.